# Separate players and prevent duplication

Tags: javascript, html

can anyone help me to separate 3 radio players with a html code and prevent the 3 radio players from becoming 3 same thing rather than being 3 different players. what code can i put between them?

for example 
All 3 radio players become the last radio player at the bottom, if you get what i mean.

```
 <script >(function (win, doc, script, source, objectName) { (win.RadionomyPlayerObject = win.RadionomyPlayerObject || []).push(objectName); win[objectName] = win[objectName] || function (k, v) { (win[objectName].parameters = win[objectName].parameters || { src: source, version: '1.1' })[k] = v; }; var js, rjs = doc.getElementsByTagName(script)[0]; js = doc.createElement(script); js.async = 1; js.src = source; rjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, rjs); }(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.radionomy.com/js/radionomy.player.js', 'radplayer'));
radplayer('url', 'yowlandurbanradio');
radplayer('type', 'mobile');
radplayer('autoplay', '0');   
radplayer('volume', '50');
radplayer('color1', '#000000');
radplayer('color2', '#ffffff');
</script>
   <div class="radionomy-player"></div>



<script>(function (win, doc, script, source, objectName) { (win.RadionomyPlayerObject = win.RadionomyPlayerObject || []).push(objectName); win[objectName] = win[objectName] || function (k, v) { (win[objectName].parameters = win[objectName].parameters || { src: source, version: '1.1' })[k] = v; }; var js, rjs = doc.getElementsByTagName(script)[0]; js = doc.createElement(script); js.async = 1; js.src = source; rjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, rjs); }(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.radionomy.com/js/radionomy.player.js', 'radplayer'));
radplayer('url', 'yowlandelectroradio');
radplayer('type', 'mobile');
radplayer('autoplay', '1');
radplayer('volume', '50');
radplayer('color1', '#000000');
radplayer('color2', '#ffffff');
</script>
  <div class="radionomy-player"></div>



<script>(function (win, doc, script, source, objectName) { (win.RadionomyPlayerObject = win.RadionomyPlayerObject || []).push(objectName); win[objectName] = win[objectName] || function (k, v) { (win[objectName].parameters = win[objectName].parameters || { src: source, version: '1.1' })[k] = v; }; var js, rjs = doc.getElementsByTagName(script)[0]; js = doc.createElement(script); js.async = 1; js.src = source; rjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, rjs); }(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.radionomy.com/js/radionomy.player.js', 'radplayer'));
radplayer('url', 'yowlandjammakerradio');
radplayer('type', 'mobile');
radplayer('autoplay', '0');
radplayer('volume', '50');
radplayer('color1', '#000000');
radplayer('color2', '#ffffff');
</script>
  <div class="radionomy-player"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't use classes. Use IDs to make each player unique. Second thing: You don't need to load the script each time you initialize a new player. So, this line is only required once:

```
<script>(function (win, doc, script, source, objectName) { (win.RadionomyPlayerObject = win.RadionomyPlayerObject || []).push(objectName); win[objectName] = win[objectName] || function (k, v) { (win[objectName].parameters = win[objectName].parameters || { src: source, version: '1.1' })[k] = v; }; var js, rjs = doc.getElementsByTagName(script)[0]; js = doc.createElement(script); js.async = 1; js.src = source; rjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, rjs); }(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.radionomy.com/js/radionomy.player.js', 'radplayer'));</script>
```

The function `radplayer(...)` seems to be loaded inside the radionomy script and parsed later here with the iframe created from the script.

I could not actually say how to give id´s to each Player (in JavaScript part). But how to do this should also be documented on the developer site there.

Comment: Thanks Moak for your response but there is no documentation on Radionomy  show how to do so its just the players html code to insert in your website.